Как поместить команду в callback?
Я сделал код в котором выполняется автоматическая регистрация пользователя, и при команде через '/' ему присылаюстя его данные, я хотел бы сделать что бы пользователь вызывал ту же функцию через инлайн клавиатуру, вот мой код:
handlers
@router.message(Command('docs'))
async def docs_show(message: Message):
await message.reply('Документы', reply_markup=kb.main)
@router.message(Command('Passport', 'passport'))
async def passport_cmd(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ49ix0j7Ud-Z8v39rVBrhkRxNdwAwZ594I__ahfyApn02AOy79OTZIQ7MvRZSyWj5hXZ4&usqp=CAU',
                               caption=f'''
: {message.from_user.id} 
: {message.from_user.first_name} 
: {message.from_user.url}
: -
 : - 
: {message.date.date()}''')


@router.callback_query(F.data == 'Passport')
async def docs_passport(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await callback.answer('')

keyboards
main = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[
    InlineKeyboardButton(text='Паспорт', callback_data='Passport')]])

